# Eslint and Browserify on Gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp, browserify, eslint

Someone could help with the the best approach for using Browserify and Eslint? I'm using Gulp to build my scripts.

```
export const TASK_SCRIPTS = (sources, path)=> {
  return gulp.src(sources, {read: false})
    .pipe($.plumber())
    .pipe($.tap(function (file) {
      $.util.log('bundling ' + file.path);
      file.contents = browserify(file.path, {debug: false})
        .transform("babelify", {presets: ["es2015"]})
        .bundle()
        .on('error', $.notify.onError(notify.bind(error)));
    }))
    .pipe($.buffer())
    .pipe($.eslint())
    .pipe($.eslint.format())
    .pipe($.eslint.failOnError())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(`${path}/js`))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload(CONFIG.reload));
};
```

I'm getting lots warning on my console regarding to the Browserify.